# How to make Scala type inference powerful enough to discover generic type parameter?

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-erasure

Assuming that I defined a function that takes implicit TypeTag:

```
  def andOptionFn[A: TypeTag](g: Int => Option[A]) = {
    val ttg = ScalaReflection.universe.typeTag[A]
    println(ttg)
    ...
  }
```

And call it:

```
andOptionFn{
v =>
  Some(v)
}
```

I would expect scala type inference to get the correct type TypeTag(Option(Int)), but instead I got:

```
TypeTag(Option(Any)) (not even a higher kind)
```

Why Scala is unable to infer it automatically in compilation time? and what works needs to be done to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct result is `TypeTag[Int]`, and Scala does print it: http://scastie.org/20273 (after you replace `ScalaReflection` with `scala.reflect.runtime`; if `ScalaReflection` is your own class, that's where you should look for the problem).

EDIT: http://scastie.org/20293 isn't a bug, it's type inference behaving precisely as designed. Call to `Seq.apply[Option[_]]` gives the expected type of `Option[_]` to each argument. When

```
andOptionFn {
  v =>
    if (v > 1) Some(v)
    else None
}
```

is typechecked *with this expected type*, the inferred `R` is of course `Any`.

EDIT 2: After reading http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference more carefully, it does seem like it should infer `Int` after all, but I am not certain. What I thought is that `Option[_]` gets reduced to `Option[Any]` (because `Option` is covariant), in which case `Any` should certainly be inferred. But http://scastie.org/20293 and http://scastie.org/20295 should behave the same, so there is at least one bug (I think) :)

Comment: Sorry, indeed the problem I encountered was caused by something else: its a bug in compiler type inference that still hasn't got resolved: see the result in http://scastie.org/20293 for a glimpse

Comment: For comparison, see 2 slightly different cases: http://scastie.org/20294 and http://scastie.org/20295

Comment: the problem is caused by andOptionFn being wrapped in another function that takes generic type parameter. Very intricate bug right?

Comment: How does in http://scastie.org/20295, Seq.apply[Option[_]] doesn't erased the type? How about Seq.apply[Option[Any]]  in http://scastie.org/20297? Haven't read the spec yet, but is the point of language design simplicity and consistency?

Comment: Yes, I agree they should be consistent. But consistently inferring `Any` in all of these cases would be fine (IMO). At any rate, I suggest asking at scala-user mailing list or reporting the inconsistency at https://issues.scala-lang.org/.