# In Scala, how to circumvent 'inferred type arguments do not conform' error?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-compiler

I have a reflective function with implicit TypeTag parameter:

```
def fromOptionFn[R: TypeTag](self: Int => Option[R]): Wrapper[R] = {
println(TypeTag[R])
...
}
```

Which for unknown reason doesn't work (see [How to make Scala type inference powerful enough to discover generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900824/how-to-make-scala-type-inference-powerful-enough-to-discover-generic-type-parame)):

```
> fromOptionFn2(v => Some(" + _))
> typeTag(Any)
```

I speculate that its caused by inferring R from Option[R], so I improve it a bit:

```
def fromOptionFn[R, Opt <: Option[R]: TypeTag](self: Int => Opt): Wrapper[R] = {
println(typeTag[Opt])
...
}
```

This time its worse, doesn't even compile, the error clearly inferred that scala is not smart enough to analyse the type:

```
> fromOptionFn2(v => Some(" + _))
Error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,Option[String]] do not conform to method fromOptionFn's type parameter bounds [R,Opt <: Option[R]]
```

So how do I temporarily circumvent this compilation problem? (Of course I can report it on Lightbend issue tracker but its too slow)

**ADDENDUM**: This problem itself is an attempted circumvention for [How to make Scala type inference powerful enough to discover generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900824/how-to-make-scala-type-inference-powerful-enough-to-discover-generic-type-parame), which might won't be fixed. In my case I don't mind getting the TypeTag of type R or Option[R], whatever works works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Scala type inference powerful enough to discover generic type parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900824/how-to-make-scala-type-inference-powerful-enough-to-discover-generic-type-parame)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an improvement, just the opposite, and Scala type inference simply doesn't support inferring `Opt` first and getting `R` from there: instead it infers `Nothing` because `R` isn't a part of any parameter types (and return type is unknown).

You could circumvent it by specifying the type parameters explicitly on every call: `fromOptionFn2[String, Option[String]](...)`. Giving the expected type should also work in this specific case, I think: `fromOptionFn2(...): Wrapper[String]`. However, a better idea would be not to use type parameter signatures like `[R, Opt <: Option[R]]` in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the type annotation in my question (please see my updated code snippet): The return type of fromOptionFn is Wrapper[R], which cannot be inferred from Opt in compilation time